# PHP: Get the value from javascript using getElementbyId

Tags: php, javascript

I would take the value of the combobox by using getelementbyID to PHP variable,
And The Code Like This

```
<select name="PROPINSI" onchange="document.getElementById('KOTAA').value = this.value" >
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>            
 </select>

<select name="KOTA" id="KOTAA">
     <?php
         $propinsi = ; //in this variable, I want take this value

         $sqll="SELECT kota FROM master_propinsi WHERE propinsi = '$propinsi'";
                   $hasill= mysql_query($sqll);


                    while($dataa = mysql_fetch_array($hasill))
                    {            
                      echo "<option value='$dataa[kota]'>$dataa[kota]</option>";             
                    }

    ?>
 </select>
```

Can SomeOne Help Me?

I really appreciate your answer
Thanks

How to get value From Combo Box with ID="KOTAA" to variable $propinsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass variable values from the current page javascript to the current page PHP code... PHP code runs at the server side and it doesn't know anything about what is going on on the client side.

You need to pass variables to PHP code from html-form using another mechanism, such as submitting form on GET or POST methods.

Comment: thanks for answer, I have try the submit, like onChange="this.form.submit()" and in $propinsi = $_GET[PROPINSI], but it not work.., anyhting Wrong with my code?

Comment: Is it inside the form tag?

Comment: yes, <select name="PROPINSI" onchange="this.form.submit()"> inside Select tag

Comment: It Resolve, with this.form.submit, the problem is $_GET, my Form method is $_POST. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't put javascript code in PHP. Although, there is an alternative: [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp)